# Deploying EJB module using jboss-maven-plugin fails with FileNotFoundException

Tags: maven, ejb, maven-plugin, jboss5.x, file-not-found

I'm trying to deploy a jar file containing my EJBs to JBoss 5, using the jboss-maven-plugin. But the plugin can't find my jar file.

I'm running the command: mvn jboss:deploy

This is what my configuration in my POM.xml looks like:

```
<build>
    <finalName>my-ejb</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <hostName>localhost</hostName>
                <port>8080</port>
                <fileNames>
                    <fileName>target/my-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</fileName>
                </fileNames>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
```

This is the error message that I get on my JBoss' console:

```
14:36:50,371 ERROR [[HtmlAdaptor]] Servlet.service() for servlet HtmlAdaptor threw exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: my-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar doesn't exist. (rootURI: file:/Users/hordine/software/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin/target/my-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, file: /Users/hordine/software/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin/target/my-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)
```

Funny thing is, "/Users/hordine/software/jboss-5.1.0.GA" is my JBOSS_HOME. Why is it looking for a jar file to deploy to JBoss inside JBoss itself?

How can I configure this file name so that it can be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to prepend the fileName with ${project.basedir}/:

```
<fileName>${project.basedir}/target/my-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</fileName>
```